# How do I change the column name of a CSV file?

Tags: bash, csv

I have multiple CSV files that looks something like this:

```
col1,col2
val1,val2
```

I want to change `col2` in each file to `column2`. How do I edit a CSV file's column name with Bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed`.

`sed -i '1s/col2/column2/' file.csv`

For multiple files, you can use a loop:

```
for f in file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
do
sed -i '1s/col2/column2/' $f
done
```

Or you can use `find` to execute `sed`:

`find . -name *.csv -exec sed -i '1s/col2/column2/' {} \;`

This will replace the `col2` in all csvs in the current directory and its sub-directories with `column2`.

Comment: This will change any col2 in any row - even if it is part of the data.  You should probably limit it to row 1 only....

Comment: When I run `sed -i 's/col2/column2/' $f`, I get this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'`. @JerryJeremiah How would I limit this to row 1?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I didn't expect data to be same as column header. But yeah, I should. See edit.

Comment: @Username What OS are you on?

Comment: @Username What happens if you try the `sed` on just one file, without the `$f`?

Comment: @Munir `sed -i '1s/col2/column2/' file.csv` works for me

Comment: @Munir Ah, I see now this works my shell script is in the same directory as the CSVs.

Comment: Double quote $f to prevent word splitting which will cause sed to fail.